# juju deployment error on manually provisioned machine

Tags: juju

I am getting the following error, when I try to deploy a service on a manually provisioned machine using juju:

```
juju deploy juju-gui --show-log
2014-05-20 13:42:31 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:302 running juju-1.18.3-unknown-amd64 [gc]
2014-05-20 13:42:31 INFO juju api.go:242 connecting to API addresses [j93716.servers.jiffybox.net:17070]
2014-05-20 13:42:31 INFO juju apiclient.go:114 state/api: dialing "wss://xxx.xxx.net:17070/"
2014-05-20 13:42:31 INFO juju apiclient.go:124 state/api: connection established
Added charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-2" to the environment.
2014-05-20 13:42:46 ERROR juju.cmd supercommand.go:305 cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to machine: cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to new machine or container: cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to new machine: use "juju add-machine ssh:[user@]<host>" to provision machines
```

juju status outputs the following:

```
environment: manual
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.3
    dns-name: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    instance-id: 'manual:'
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1996M
  "1":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.18.3
    dns-name: xxx.xxx.xxx.yyy
    instance-id: manual:xxx.xxx.xxx.net
    series: precise
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1996M
services:
  juju-gui:
    charm: cs:trusty/juju-gui-2
    exposed: true
    units:
      juju-gui/0:
        agent-state: pending
```

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4):

Judging by the juju status output, you've bootstrapped a manual environment (using `juju bootstrap`, which is different from manual provisioning, done using `juju add-machine ssh:[user@]host`).

Manual environments are special - they consist only of a single machine and it **cannot start or stop additional machines automatically**, including on `juju deploy`. To add another machine, use `juju add-machine ssh:[user@]host` first, then `juju deploy juju-gui --to #`, where # is the juju machine id of the machine you've just added (run `juju status` to see it). You can also use `juju deploy juju-gui --to 0` to deploy Juju GUI on the bootstrap machine.

`juju add-machine ssh:[user@]host` can be used in any bootstrapped environment to manually provision an external machine and add it to the environment. But with a manually bootstrapped environment, that's the only way to add machines, and you have to specify placement for services and units when deploying, with `--to <machine-id>` explicitly.

I hope that clears up any confusion. We definitely need better documentation on that I suppose.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Unfortunately now I run into another problem:

    ````juju deploy juju-gui --to 0
    Added charm "cs:trusty/juju-gui-2" to the environment.
    ERROR cannot assign unit "juju-gui/0" to machine 0: series does not match````

Comment: @chmanie Can you ask the series question as a new one? It's unrelated to this issue, that way we can have one solution per post, thanks!

Comment: If you're satisfied with the answer for your original question, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: If you use juju-gui, it does not add the --to # on charm deploy and so all charms fail?